# Oracle database connects via sqlplus but listener isnt running on my Ubuntu

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu, listener

On my windows laptop, i installed oracle Virtual machine and installed Ubuntu 18.04. And then i installed oracle 11g so I can practice writing shell scripts that update oracle database.
I can easily connect to database using sqlplus and create tables etc..
However when i wrote a simple script to connect to database and perform a simple task my script never connects to oracle database.
Also i checked that the listener is not running and when i check the current status I get the below error:

TNS-12541: TNS: No Listener
TNS-12560: TNS: Protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No Listener
Linux Error: 111: Connection refused

I am new to everything please can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you at some point shutdown the Database in that script? If you do, know that by default the Oracle Database's listener shuts down in place with it. If that's the case, then you need a static entry in the listener.ora file (parameter file for the listener), so that to keep the service running, even if the DB is down.

Comment: On another note - I think you're using the sqlplus that comes with the Oracle Home, after you install the Database - this should always work. However, when connecting externally (through SQLNET, that is your "script" which you didn't disclose), this connection uses SQLNET channel to get there. The Database uses a listener process (using listener.ora parameter file) to "listen" for those external connections, so may be this is what you're lacking. In Ubuntu, open the terminal (source the environment if needed) and execute: `lsnrctl start`.

Comment: @g00dy has provided great places to start checking. In addition to their advice, I would also recommend checking to make sure that the TNS info you are using is properly formatted. Here is the 11g documentation on local naming parameters: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/tnsnames.htm#NETRF007 

You do not need to define every connect descriptor, something like this is ok:

ORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = [MACHINE].[DOMAIN])(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle)
    )
  )

Comment: Also, you can use tnsping to test the connection from terminal. Using the above comment as an example, you would enter 'tnsping oracle' and the system will test the connection. An example is below, successful attempt will return OK message. 

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=[MACHINE].[DOMAIN])(PORT=1521)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVER=DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME=
oracle)))
OK (150 msec)